# $ c(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n -1} t(i) c(n - i) $?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, closed-form

It is well known that

$$ a(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} a(n - i) $$

$$ b(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} i b(n -i) $$

Can be expressed by fibonacci and powers of 2.

So What about

$$ c(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n -1} t(i) c(n - i) $$

Where $t(i)$ is the i th triangular number ?

Closed form or asymptotics ?

How about generalizations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generating functions
\begin{eqnarray*}
C(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n x^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the recurrence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} c_n x^n =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{i+1}{2} c_n x^n  
\end{eqnarray*}
Now invert the order of the sums and add in the first term
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} c_n x^n =1+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \binom{i+1}{2} x^{i}\sum_{n=i+1}^{n-1}  c_n x^{n-i}  \\
C(x)= 1+\frac{x}{(1-x)^3} C(x) \\
C(x) = \frac{(1-x)^3}{(1-x)^3-x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
More generally 
 \begin{eqnarray*}
m_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{i+m-1}{m} m_{n-i}
\end{eqnarray*}
will give
\begin{eqnarray*}
M(x) = \frac{(1-x)^m}{(1-x)^m-x}.
\end{eqnarray*}